# 0 non-null float64 on Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsILy.png (screenshot of my code on Jupyter)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tickers = ['PG', 'MSFT', 'F', 'GE']
mydata = pd.DataFrame()
for t in tickers:    
    mydata[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='morningstar', start = '2005-1-1')['Close']
mydata.info()
```

gives:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 3430 entries, (PG, 2005-01-03 00:00:00) to (PG, 2018-02-23 00:00:00)
Data columns (total 4 columns):
PG      3430 non-null float64
MSFT    0 non-null float64
F       0 non-null float64
GE      0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 144.1+ KB
```

Attached is the code I've used to get data on closing price for these stocks. However, i keep running into the issue of NaN for all stocks AFTER the first one. It doesn't show data for it. I have no Idea what I am doing wrong. Also, I am using morningstar because neither yahoo or google are compatible with Jupyter for some weird reason. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please do not post links to your code.  Please also take note of how to format your code.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the results of the `wb.DataReader(...)` calls look sensible for all four symbols? That is, does the problem arise when *getting* the data in the first place, or when combining the data into a single dataframe?

Comment: @MarkDickinson by sensible do you mean that the tickers are correct? If so, yes there are.

Comment: @KindStranger is there a reason I can't post links? Also, how do I format my code?

Comment: @OmiePython: No, I mean that you should look at the four *outputs* of `wb.DataReader` and check that they look sensible: that is, that they have no unexpected missing data. There are two possibliities: (1) the `wb.DataReader` results are _already_ missing the data you're interested in, or (2) the NaNs are somehow introduced when you merge the 4 sets of results into a single dataframe. As the person seeing the error, you're the best-placed person to investigate which of those two possibilities is actually occurring.